# SCIM API for Sailpoint

Tags: postman, scim, sailpoint

I am completely new to SCIM API.

Need your help in setting up and getting the entitlement metadata via SCIM API from sailpoint and fetch it in Postman.

Any dummy code would be very helpful which I will edit as per my exact need.

Answer (score 2):

Select get method and add basic authentication for entering your username and password.

Put in the url: YOURDOMAIN/scim/v2/Entitlements (f.e. http://localhost:8080/identityiq/scim/v2/Entitlements) => you will get all entitlements back, if there are some entitlements.

Maybe that can help you: https://developer.sailpoint.com/SCIM/index.html#entitlements-entitlements